# User account signup and signin with Google in Ionic/Cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing a hybrid mobile app based on my exisiting web application in Ionic, i.e Cordova+Angularjs. So all the data must be common for phone and web app.

I want to provide an alternative to users where they can skip the registration form and directly sign-up with my system using their Google account. 
Once they register, my server's DB should have that added user. And after that, the user can use their account by signing in with the Google account. I could figure out how it'd work on the web application, but for phones, it seems to be different. So I need help of how the user's tokens/email would be used to authenticate once they register using Google account.

Comment: Do you have InAppBrowser included in your app?

Comment: Yes, I had added it to test some plugins.

Comment: You might want to take advantage of ngCordova for this.  I included the Oauth module which has Google support.  Have the user sign in with Google on the device, then call one of the Google+ APIs to get information such as name, email, ect. to be sent back to your server.  You could possibly use the email as your primary key.

Comment: So...I send the client ID of my app to Google, then the user has to grant access to my app; once done their permanent access token is generated (which is stored aside the user email in my DB).
And then each time user sends login request, the same token is received by the app, which will then send it to my DB and authenticate?
Am i getting this right?